# Get NSDate from start of 7 days ago

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to do some simple 7 day history plotting. Given the current `NSDate.date`, I want to get the NSDate that corresponds to the start of day, 7 days ago. So basically 7 days prior to 0.00 this morning.

What I've tried, is the following:

```
// decompose the current date, do I need more component fields?
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSCalendar.currentCalendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: NSDate.date]; 
NSLog(@"components: %@", comps);
// Back day up 7 days. Will this wrap appropriate across month/year boundaries?
comps.day -= 7;
NSDate *origin = comps.date;
NSLog(@"new date: %@", origin);
```

What I assumed was that by just specifying `NSDayCalendarUnit`, the other things would be defaults (like start of day, etc). Unfortunately, `origin` ends up as `(null)`. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a new date you should know not only a day but also a month and a year. So you should add NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit. Also you should setup calendar and probably timezone properties of NSDateComponents's instance:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSCalendar.currentCalendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: NSDate.date];
comps.calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
comps.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSLog(@"components: %@", comps);
// Back day up 7 days. Will this wrap appropriate across month/year boundaries?
comps.day -= 7;
NSDate *origin = comps.date;
NSLog(@"new date: %@", origin);
```

Comment: I actually want the date to be relative to the current time zone. IOW, if I'm in PST, I want the start of day 7 days ago in PST. Will that `.timeZone` setter help or hurt that?

Comment: Answered my own question through trial and error. Indeed, I do not want the `.timeZone` set. But the `.calendar` is necessary. Which is odd, you'd think the calendar returning the components would have set its calendar since it was derived from that.